# Send a List<string> to a wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf

I've tried to look everywhere to find an answer to this problem, but no luck.. so i've turned to the experts here for some help!

I have a wcf service in c# is fully working... it does some magic and it sends a List to the server. The server can read these PO objects fine. However, i now have a problem when inside PO there is a list...

```
public class PO
{
    /* omitted */
    [DataMember]
    public Object BasicContent { get; set; }
}
```

When BasicContent is a List i get the following error:

*"There was an error while trying to serialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:objectToPersist. The InnerException message was 'Type 'System.String[]' with data contract name 'ArrayOfstring:http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays' is not expected. Add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.'.  Please see InnerException for more details."*

I have tried adding `[ServiceKnownType(typeof(List<string>))]` or `[ServiceKnownType(typeof(string[]))]` all over the place by no avail...

Can anyone give me a hand on what I can do?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the type to String or String[] or List depending on what your setting it to.

Comment: tried, didnt seem to work as over the write i think that the string[] and list<string> are both handled as ArrayOfString

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a ServiceKnownType for just String

```
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(string))]
```

Comment: I can send strings over - they work in the 'BasicContent' bit OK